# Tensorflow object detection slow inference time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I need to measure the inference time for a TF1 object detection model. I have developed the following code by looking at various tutorials and at the official Tensorflow Github repository.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import time

from collections import defaultdict
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
%matplotlib inline

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging (1)
import pathlib

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')           # Suppress TensorFlow logging (2)

# Enable GPU dynamic memory allocation
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

# Initialize tf.Graph()
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile('/home/luigi/Downloads/SSD_MobileNet_300000/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

# Loads labels
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap('/home/luigi/Downloads/DOTA-3/train/Objects_label_map.pbtxt')
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=15, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Run Inference and populates results in a dict.
def run_inference(graph, image):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = [output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs]
      tensor_dict = {}
      tensor_keys = ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores', 'detection_classes']
      for key in tensor_keys:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)
      
      # Actual inference.
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict, feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
  return output_dict
    
path = '/home/luigi/Downloads/test/'

#[os.path.join('/home/luigi/Downloads/test/', image_path)]
for image_path in os.listdir(path):
  input_path = os.path.join(path, image_path)
  print('Evaluating:', input_path)
  image = Image.open(input_path)
  img_width, img_height = image.size
  image_np = np.array(image.getdata()).reshape((img_height, img_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
  # Run inference.
  start = time.time()
  output_dict = run_inference(detection_graph, image_np)
  end = time.time()
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
  plt.imshow(image_np)
  print("Prediction time for: " + image_path + " " + str(end-start))
```

I think that for some reason related to the code above, the inference times that I get are slow and could be improved. I have been looking online but haven't had any luck finding anything useful. Any tips?

Comment: Hi! Did you try 2.x versions yet?

Comment: Hi! I can’t - I need to replicate an experiment done with TF1